# Why does this Java method appear to have two return types?

Tags: java, methods

```
public <E extends Foo> List<E> getResult(String s);
```

where `Foo` is my own class.

What is the return type of this method? Why does it seem to have two return types?

Comment: It will return a `List<? extends Foo>`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza `?` is specified by the caller. The method itself has no choice. All it can legitimately return is an empty `List`, a `List` of `null`s, `null` or throw an exception/not return.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, you don't have two return types. It's a [*generic method*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) you are seeing.

- `<E extends Foo>` → You are declaring a generic type for your method;
- `List<E>` → This is your return type.

Your method can have a generic type `E` which is a subclass of `Foo`. The return type of the method is a `List<Foo-or-any-subtype-of-Foo>`.

Answer (score 7):

The return type is `List<E>`.  The clause `<E extends Foo>` is not a return type; it is a generic type declaration, specifying that the particular type `E` must be a `Foo` (or a subclass of `Foo`).  This is standard syntax for declaring a generic method.

Comment: `E` can be a child class of `Foo`.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the Java [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html) pertaining to generics.

```
<E extends Foo> // declares the bounds for the generic type `E`
List<E> // declares the return value
```

The return type of the method is `List<E>`.