# How to understand the Java doc syntax

Tags: java, documentation

For example, I see

> static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void parallelSort(T[] a)
>
> Sorts the specified array of objects into
> ascending order, according to the natural ordering of its elements.

So I get this is a static method and what it does, but what does  `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` mean (return type, but what is it, is it the same way I would write in the code, or a syntax used in the documentation to show several possible values)

Comment: You need to learn about generics.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does this Java method appear to have two return types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281904/why-does-this-java-method-appear-to-have-two-return-types)

Comment: It's *not* a return type. `void` is the return type. It's a specifier for *type inference*

Comment: @SLaks Is this syntax is same as it appears in code, or some type of annotation, for example, in SQL u would use `CREATE [TABLE|VIEW|PROCEDURE..` to show various possible values and if they are optional or not. Is it the same case here, or is this the exact syntax?

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: You need to learn the basic syntax for declaring generic type parameters.

Comment: If the question is about the syntax of the entire Javadoc, then the question is far too broad and should be flagged. If the question is specific to the example provided, then the clause "*This question is not specific to Generics*" needs to be removed. You even accepted an answer specific about type inference, which is specific to generics.

Comment: @john I wanted to know if the `<?`  etc is code or part of the doc and if part of the doc, what it means. The answer I accepted answers that for me. Feel free to format my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` is **not** the return type. `void` is the return type. A generic specification before the return type is for *type inference*.

The argument (`T[]`) type is inferred from the call, and must be something that `extends Comparable<? super T>`

Suppose you have a class defined:

```
class Foo extends Comparable<Foo> { ... }
```

That means:

```
Foo[] fooArray = ...
parallelSort(fooArray);
```

is legal, and inside the `parallelSort()` method, `T` will be of type `Foo` (which implements the `Comparable` interface)

Here's a simple, less complicated example without the recursive type. In this case, it says it returns a list of the inferred type:

```
public static <T> <List<T>> myMethod(T arg) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    list.add(arg);
    return list;
}
```

The type is inferred from the argument:

```
List<String> list = myMethod("hi");
```