# Generics, need layman explanation?

Tags: java, generics

I came across the following snippet of code that uses generics.

```
public class Generics<T> {

   public static <T> T replaceIfNull(T objectToCheck, T defaultValue) {
      return objectToCheck == null ? defaultValue : objectToCheck;
   }

   public static <T> boolean CheckIfNull(T objectToCheck) {
      return objectToCheck == null ? true : false;
   }
}
```

I am having a difficult time truly understanding how generics work, formed and used. I have a high level understanding, meaning that I know the definition of generics. And by the definition my interpretation of this code snippet is that replaceIfNull method checks for null values of any object and then returns a default value (whatever that is). And that CheckIfNull method is similar, in that it checks null value for any object.

But how does this work? Why is the method formed with `<T>`, which seems to be a type and then there is `T` following. I do not understand this syntax, `<T> T` means? And how does `T` become a type in the parameters? How come this method, for example, could not be written as

```
public static Object replaceIfNull(Object objectToCheck, Object defaultValue) {
   return objectToCheck == null ? defaultValue : objectToCheck;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your clarification.

Comment: Java generics are resolved by the compiler at compile time.  Basically, the type that is entered as T in Generics<T> is substituted into all occurrances of T in the class.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: [Why does this Java method appear to have two return types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281904/why-does-this-java-method-appear-to-have-two-return-types)

Comment: @DwB, I think I understand what you are saying. So the use of generics is like a safety feature, presumably for runtime issues. Its like turning runtime issues into compile-time errors?

Comment: Generics allow you to reuse code so that you don't need to create a separate class for each different input. Take the ArrayList class for instance... Without generics, you would need to have a separate ArrayList for each primitive or Object type: ArrayList<Integer>, ArrayList<Object>, ArrayList<Double>, etc...

Comment: As a sidenote, I always cringe when I read `<expr> ? true : false`. Just remove the ternary expression, since it does nothing.

Comment: Can I get an explanation for the down vote? Someone is just down voting posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with answering your last question. The method rewrite with `Object` instead of generics has two drawbacks. First, it will not work with primitives (which might not be a real drawback in this case, since you are checking against `null`, and primitives cannot take null values, but still...). Second, it will require casting. If , for example, you use this method on two strings, like `replaceIfNull(myString, "Default Value")`, then you would expect to get a String as an output, right? But instead the method declared to be returning `Object`; so there is no way for compiler to know that it will return a String, and you will have to do casting every time you use it: `String result = (String) replaceIfNull(myString, "Default Value");' Generics were introduced specifically to fix this situation.

You can think of generics as templates; whatever type you put in the angle braces will be used later in the code whenever you use type parameter. So, `<T>` means: "Here will go some type; replace `T` with it everywhere in the code".

And the last question is about the method signature. I think here you mixed up two different methods of using generics - on a class level, and on a method level.  Since you've already introduced the type parameter on the class level, there is no need to do it again on a method level, so I think you can safely remove `<T>` from method declaration.

I suggest you read a more detailed explanation on generics here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: This is simplest form of answer. I will accept this. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The subject of Generics is very broad and you can read about it extensively on Oracle's website or on Stack Overflow.

> Why is the method formed with `<T>`, which seems to be a type and then there is `T` following.

This is a generic method. The `<T>` declares a new type variable with no bounds.

```
//                v return type   
public static <T> T replaceIfNull(T objectToCheck, T defaultValue) {
//             ^ new type variable                 ^ type variable used as a type
```

Within the method body, since the type variable has no bounds, `T` can, at most, be interpreted as `Object`. You're only going to have access to method declared in `Object` on expressions of type `T`.

Outside the method, ie. in invocation contexts, the type variable `T` will receive a concrete type value. That is, it will either infer it from its invocation context or it will be provided explicitly.

For example, in

```
replaceIfNull(someStringVar, otherStringVar);
```

the type variable `T` will be bound to `String`, so all usages of `T` will be interpreted as `String`. You could therefore do

```
String notNull = replaceIfNull(someStringVar, " not null ");
```

You could also provide the type argument explicitly

```
Generics.<String>replaceIfNull(nullVar, " not null ");
```

and now again the type variable will be bound to `String`.

Note that the type variable `T` declared at the type level

```
public class Generics<T>
```

is completely different from the type variable `T` declared in the method.